# Want ${workspaceFolder} to emit forward slashes on Windows?

Tags: gcc, visual-studio-code, mingw, gnu-make, vscode-tasks

I'm configuring a VSCode task in tasks.json, and I need to pass the ${workspaceFolder} to a 'make' command, however it needs to be forward slashes, not back slashes.

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"echoCommand": true, 
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build",
        "type": "shell",
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "command": "make",
        "args": [
            "APPDIR=\"${workspaceFolder}\""
        ]
. . .
```

Is there any way to modify ${workspaceFolder} to emit forward slashes on Windows?
Or, is there such a thing as a macro, where I can search and replace?

EDIT:
My root issue is that GNU make seems to escape the backslashes incoming from APPDIR, for example: C:\somedirectory\someotherdirectory\athirddirectory.
I thought if I could switch to forward slashes, it would fix the issue.
I have no control over, and cannot edit, the make file.

Thanks

-John

Comment: same pb, my script work on linux and mac but not with windows

Comment: You probably have the `cygpath` and `sh` commands available. I would try replacing `make APPDIR=xxx` with `sh -c "make APPDIR=$(cygpath 'xxx')"`. Beware of the tricky quotes!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56904259/11585798) might be your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use variable `extension.commandvariable.workspace.workspaceFolderPosix` from extension [command-variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) where you need `${workspaceFolder}` with forward slashes. There are also other useful substitutions in this extension.

Comment: The command-variable extension worked for me. Use ${command:extension.commandvariable.workspace.folder} since extension.commandvariable.workspace.workspaceFolderPosix is already deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Although not explicitly stated, it sounds like you're on Windows and using Cygwin make.

Basically using Johan's suggestion, here is a complete `tasks.json` that uses `cygpath -m` to pass forward slashes to `make`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build hello world",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "d:/cygwin64/bin/sh",
            "args": [
                "-c",
                "make APPDIR=$(cygpath -m '${workspaceFolder}')"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is a sample `Makefile` to be called:

```
$(info APPDIR is "$(APPDIR)")

helloworld.exe: helloworld.cpp
    g++ -g -Wall -std=c++11 -o $@ helloworld.cpp
```

When I press Ctrl+Shift+B to invoke this task, I see in the Terminal window:

```
> Executing task in folder cpphello: d:/cygwin64/bin/sh -c "make APPDIR=$(cygpath -m 'D:\wrk\learn\vscode\cpphello')" <

APPDIR is "D:/wrk/learn/vscode/cpphello"
make: 'helloworld.exe' is up to date.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

This uses the `-m` (mixed) switch to `cygpath` to get what looks like a Windows path but using forward slashes.  `cygpath` has other options; see `cygpath --help`.

Two subtleties here:

1. I specify the path to `sh` explicitly.  That is because I also
   have [git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) on my $PATH,
   and it comes before my Cygwin path so that vscode will use that
   `git`.  But git for Windows also has `sh.exe`, and if that one
   is used here, `make` blows up with a Cygwin DLL error.
2. I had to change the default VSCode shell to `cmd.exe`, whereas
   the default is `powershell.exe`.  The problem with powershell
   here is that VSCode uses single quotes when passing arguments to
   it, whereas my solution requires that VSCode use double-quotes,
   which it does with `cmd.exe`.  To change the shell, use the
   "Terminal: Select Default Shell" command from the palette
   (Ctrl+Shift+P).

Finally, I'll note that all of this nonsense can be avoided if, in your situation, you can create an intermediate `bash` shell script rather than invoking `make` directly.  The `tasks.json` language is not very powerful, and the quirky shells VSCode knows how to invoke on Windows (namely `cmd.exe` and `powershell.exe`) add extra complexity and fragility.

Comment: It seems like it doesn't work any more, because VSCode put own quotes into the command:

`Executing task: c:/cygwin64/bin/sh -c 'make APPDIR=$(cygpath -m 'C:\work\project')' 

C:\work\project): -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'

C:\work\project): -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

With double quotes it doesn't work either.

Comment: @Rom098 Did you change your shell to `cmd.exe`?  What version of VSCode are you using?

Comment: You're right. I missed the explanation about changing shell from PS to CMD. Thanks, it works now.