# How to reverse backslashes in ${relativeFile} in Visual Studio Code in launch.json?

Tags: node.js, configuration, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I'm trying to configure (Windows) Visual Studio Code `launch.json` to launch `jest` tests for the current file. To get the path I use `${relativeFile}` variable which gives a string with backslashes like this `"src\services\some-service.spec.ts"`, although in the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) slashes look just normal.

It seems that `jest` doesn't accept this kind of path because of reversed slashed. When I manually pass the same path with normal slashes it works just fine.

The question is is there any way to reverse backslashes in VSCode path predefined variables like `${relativeFile}` or maybe some workarounds?

Comment: I found it [on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/40288). Sorry, I didn't see, that it is still unsolved.

Comment: I saw that thread and I had no idea where he found that example, probably it was just an idea.

Answer (score 7):

## [Update] 2020-05-01

Now jest cli supports option [--runTestsByPath](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#--runtestsbypath), so that you can explicitly specify a file path rather than a pattern, which allows you to use `\` on windows.

So the following `launch.json` should work:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Jest Current File",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [
        "node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
        "--runInBand",
        "--runTestsByPath",
        "${relativeFile}"
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

## The following is the original answer:

---

It seems that jest doesn't plan to work with `\` and vscode doesn't plan to provide features to replace chars in Predefined variables.

But there are some workarounds:

1. use `${fileBasename}` instead of `${relativeFile}`
2. Or use [input variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_input-variables) so that vscode prompt you to input custom test name when you debug.

Here is an example `launch.json` for the above two workarounds.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Jest Current FileBaseName",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [
        "node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
        "--runInBand",
        "${fileBasename}"
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jest Custom",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [
        "node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
        "--runInBand",
        "${input:testName}"
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "type": "promptString",
      "id": "testName",
      "description": "The file or name you want to test",
      "default": "${fileBaseName}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use variable `extension.commandvariable.file.relativeFilePosix` from extension [command-variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) where you need `${relativeFile}` with forward slashes. There are also other useful substitutions in this extension.

Comment: Using VS Code to run jest tests through the debugger required forward slashes, this is the only fix that works. Thank you so much!

Comment: Doesn't work; it changes paths to be like `/c/folder/file.txt` instead of `c:/folder/file.txt`. 

Answer (score 0):

This problem is very similar to one I gave an [answer to elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57730963/2659307).  To summarize the explanation there:

1. Instead of directly running `node ...`, run `bash -c node ...` so you can use shell command substitution in the command line.
2. Pass the path through the `cygpath -m` program to get forward slashes, something like `$(cygpath -m ${relativeFile})`.

See the linked answer for more details and examples.

Comment: This answer saved my day.  I was going with the fileBasenameNoExtension approach.  Then I created a monorepo with common naming and that broke my ability to debug one file from anywhere.

Thanks!