# VSCode using relative paths in build task on remote set up

Tags: linux, windows, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to add a build task to build the current file, just a simple "make path/to/file.o".  I'm using vscode on windows 10 over a remote SSH connection to linux.

However, if I use ${relativeFileDirname} it converts the path separators to windows format.  Eg...

```
${fileDirname}=/home/me/git/project/data/source
${relativeFileDirname}=data\source
```

I've read about explorer.copyRelativePathSeparator.  Can that be applied to the build task in tasks.json?  Or is there another way?

This is the build task...

```
{
    "type": "cppbuild",
    "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
    "command": "/usr/bin/make",
    "args": [
        "${relativeFileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.o"
    ],
    "options": {
        "cwd": "/home/me/git/project"
    },
    "problemMatcher": [
        "$gcc"
    ],
    "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
    },
    "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/gcc",
    "presentation": {
        "clear": true
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55190115/how-to-reverse-backslashes-in-relativefile-in-visual-studio-code-in-launch-js

Answer (score 0):

There is an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) for Visual Studio Code for this purpose that, after many failed attempts to use string substitution with `bash` built-ins and `sed`, was the only working solution for me:

```
"customOptions": "--workdir /home/user/${command:extension.commandvariable.file.relativeFileDirnamePosix}",
```