# Forward slashes instead of back in filepath

Tags: json, bash, command-line, visual-studio-code

How do I replace the backslashes with forward slashes in the Visual Studio Code build task argument.

I've tried using backslashes in my Bash command, but the console simply removes the slashes.

```
"command": "xxxxxxxx.exe",
"type": "shell",
"args": [
    "--dir=${workspaceFolder}",
]
```

In the console it appears to be:

```
> Executing task: xxxxxxxx.exe --dir=C:UsersUserDesktopProject
```

But I want it to be:

```
> Executing task: xxxxxxxx.exe --dir=C:/Users/User/Desktop/Project/
```

Comment: what is the workspaceFolder variable ? Is it managed by vscode ?

Comment: Yes it's managed by VSCode. It's a predefined variable, please read [this article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_predefined-variables).

Comment: The program can't parse a relative path, so it has to use the full path.

Answer (score 2):

Something using bash built-in `${variable//string/substitution}`:

```
"command": "xxxxxxxx.exe",
"type": "shell",
"args": [
    "--dir=${workspaceFolder//\\/\/}",
]
```

Answer (score 2):

As for me, **just switch default shell** to cmd done the job. I installed `git-bash` as my default shell within `vscode`. When I tried to debug ts file, the shell complained something like your case, the path is a string without any slash or backslash.

This is my launch.json.

```
{
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug Current",
      "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "program": "${file}",
      "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/*.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you double the backslashes? They are a quoting character, so you likely have to use one to quote the next.

```
$: echo "C:\Users\Public" | sed 's,\\,/,g'
C:/Users/Public
```

Using parameter expension without spawning a `sed` -

```
$: x="C:\Users\Public"
$: echo "${x//\\/\/}"
C:/Users/Public
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get it to work. It runs as: `> Executing task: xxxxxxxx.exe --dir=${workspaceFolder//\//}`, and the `${workspaceFolder//\//}` is not replaced with `C:/Users/User`.

Comment: Not `${workspaceFolder//\//}` - c.f. `//` to say "replace this across the whole string", `\/` to say replace "literally a forward slash", and then `/` to "with:"...then you don't give it a replacement pattern. Use `${workspaceFolder//\\/\/}" so the `\\` means literally a backward slash", then the `/` is "with:" a `\/`, "literally a forward slash.

Comment: This is "leaning toothpick syndrome", which is why I used commans in the `sed` pattern. :(

Comment: A backward slash quotes the next character, which we use both to quote the backward slash we want replaced, and to quote the forward slash we want as the replacement pattern.

Comment: Wow that actually worked. I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: I've done worse, recently, in an answer, lol... don't feel bad.