# VS Code error messages when including iostream

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compilation, include

[image]

Error messages are:

> #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (D:\DINO\code\pong\pong.cc).C/C++(1696)

> cannot open source file "crtdbg.h" (dependency of "iostream")C/C++(1696)

I used to solve this issue, but it just comes once again.

I have searched, but they don't work..

Also, I wonder when clicking run, is it normal to have

> bash: cd: d:\DINO\code\pong" && g++ pong.cc -o pong && d:DINOcodepong"pong: No such file or directory

in the Code terminal and we need to manually compile it with g++, rather than VS Code done that for us, while in bash there's no this error?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: have you followed the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)?

Comment: If your `bash` is anything like normal `bash`, the backslashes aren't directory separators. Replace them with `/`

Comment: Alan! For crying out loud! Are you trying to put us out of work? If people actually read the <expletive deleted>ing manual, none of us would have jobs. Stop giving away the great trade secrets!

Comment: As @TedLyngmo said the problem is using the wrong path separator for the bash shell. I am not sure how to have VS Code generate paths for bash. You may want to switch to using powershell or cmd.exe if you can't find the setting. Edit: this may help: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/62672082/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62672082/487892)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the include problem by watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1oQbEzAMUA).

I pasted the `mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\8.1.0` to the includePath, `mingw64\bin\g++.exe` to the complierPath, modified all `\` to `\\`, followed instructions from vs code output, and the error just disappeared!